# How to get list of all scripts in the Perl CPAN release with metacpan API

Tags: perl, elasticsearch

Here is the task. There is some CPAN release (example: https://metacpan.org/release/cpan-outdated) I need to get the list of scripts that are in that release (the "script" is any file that is situated in a `bin` or `script` directory).

For release cpan-outdated the answer is `cpan-outdated`, because there is a file `script/cpan-outdated` — https://metacpan.org/source/TOKUHIROM/cpan-outdated-0.28/script

I can download the tar.gz with release, uncompress it and get all the info I need, but the Metacpan already has this information. Metacpan uses ElasticSearch, so I want to find out the request that will give me the info I need. I'm sure that Metacpan has this info, because on the site with metacpan api examples (http://explorer.metacpan.org ) there is an example of showing top level files of all the releases.

Comment: What's your question? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

Load and parse the `MANIFEST` that every good CPAN distribution comes with

```
http://api.metacpan.org/source/<AUTHOR>/<DISTRO>-<VERSION>/MANIFEST
```

Comment: I agree this is the simplest technique. It may miss occasional edge cases where the script does not exist in the tarball but gets built by `make` during the normal build process, but this is likely to be a minority of cases.